# Solving a simple BVP (with an error)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, manipulate, warning-messages

I am trying to redo the method given in

[Solving a simple BVP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/solving-a-simple-bvp)

which is very nice, to my equation

```
2 + 2 u'[x2]^2 + u[x2] u''[x2]
```

where `x2=[-1.,1.]` and `u[-1.]=u[1.]=1/10`. I copyed the steps and change the pamareters, obviously. My code in this case is

```
Manipulate[eq = 2 + 2 u'[x2]^2 + u[x2] u''[x2] == 0;
 ic = {u[-1] == ic0, u[1] == ic1};
 sol = First@NDSolve[Flatten[{eq, ic}], u[x2], {x2, -1, to}];
 Plot[u[x2] /. sol, {x2, -1, to}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> 50, 
  FrameLabel -> {{u[x2], None}, {x2, 
     Style[Row[{"solution to ", 
        2 + 2 Derivative[1][u][x2]^2 + 
          u[x2] (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x2] == 0}], 12]}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Thickness[.001]]], {{to, 1, 
   "to?"}, 0, 1, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ic0, 1/10, "u(x20)"}, 0, 1, .01, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ic1, 1/10, "u(x21)"},
   0, 1, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

As a result, I get

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during
>   this calculation.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity
>   encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity
>   encountered.
>
> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x2
>   == -1..

and

> ReplaceAll::reps: {2+2 (u^[Prime])[-0.999959]^2+u[-0.999959]
>   (u^[Prime][Prime])[-0.999959]==0,u[-1]==1/10,u[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/solving-a-simple-bvp)==1/10} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing.
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {2. +2. (u^[Prime])[-0.999959]^2+u[-0.999959]
>   (u^[Prime][Prime])[-0.999959]==0.,u[-1.]==0.1,u[1.]==0.1} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing.
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {2+2 (u^[Prime])[-0.959143]^2+u[-0.959143]
>   (u^[Prime][Prime])[-0.959143]==0,u[-1]==1/10,u[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16644/solving-a-simple-bvp)==1/10} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing.
>
> General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed
>   during this calculation.

I ask the same question giving my whole code and parameters in

[My code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167023/problem-with-a-numeric-1-0-in-ndsolvevalue?noredirect=1#comment440988_167023)

where you can see that `u[-1.]=u[1.]=1/100`, but thats not the main point.

Comment: you can use "Quiet" to get rid of 1/0.

Comment: @GopalVerma It didnt work.

Comment: But, using   sol = First@Quiet[NDSolve[Flatten[{eq, ic}], u[x2], {x2, -1, to}]] we found that there is no Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Comment: @GopalVerma I saw whats is acctually the function of `Quiet` in the code, and it look it only hides the message not eliminate the `1/0` singularity. I think the problem is that the range of `x2` passes through `0`, but I dont know how to modify that because that range is required.

Comment: One can also avid the singulartiy by adding a small number u[x2]+10^-9. Did you find the the solution for x2>0?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic [Shooting Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html) does not suffer errors well.  It seems to give up when poorly chosen initial conditions lead to an error.  In this case, there is a lower limit on the initial condition for `u'[-1]`, below which the solution develops a singularity.  It is very close to the actual solution, so the built-in shooting method inevitably runs into a singularity and fails. Thus a manual approach seems to be necessary.  We add an extrapolation handler that will cause `FindRoot` to increase the initial condition when this happens.

Also, one cannot have boundary conditions `u[-1] == 0` nor `u[1] == 0`, since in solving for `u''[x2]`, the equation is divided by `u[x2]`.  So I limited the input range on the sliders for the BCs.

```
Manipulate[
 eq = 2 + 2 u'[x2]^2 + u[x2] u''[x2] == 0;
 ic = {u[-1] == ic0, u[1] == ic1};
 With[{pen = 3/ic0^2},   (* slightly informed guess *)
  psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    Flatten[{eq, {u[-1] == ic0, u'[-1] == p0}}], u, {x2, -1, 1}, {p0},
     "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {p0 - pen &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
  ];
 Quiet[
  usol = psol[p0] /. FindRoot[psol[p0][1] == ic1,
     {p0, 2/ic0^2, E/ic0^2}],  (* starting values from inspection of psol *)
  ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz];
 Dynamic@Plot[usol[x2], {x2, -1, to}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, All}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], 
   ImagePadding -> 50, 
   FrameLabel -> {{u[x2], None}, {x2, 
      Style[Row[{"solution to ", 
         2 + 2 u'[x2]^2 + u[x2] u''[x2] == 0}], 12]}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Thickness[.001]]],
 {{to, 1, "to?"}, 0, 1, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ic0, 1/10, "u(x20)"}, 0.001, 1, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ic1, 1/10, "u(x21)"}, 0.001, 1, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
usol'[-1]  (*  p0  found by FindRoot for  ic0 = 0.001  is approx  E/ic0^2 *)
(*  2.78641*10^6  *)
```

Note how large the derivative is compared to the size of the solution.  It might be hard to lower the limit on the slider for `ic0`, without increasing precision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to ask how did you get those values for `p0`, `[p0, 2/ic0^2, E/ic0^2]`?

Comment: Another doubt, how did you get that "slightly informed guess" for `pen`?

Comment: For `p0`, when I got the answer for `ic0 = 0.1`, I thought `p0` is about `100` or so, or about `1/ic0^2` (it was actually 200+, so `2/ic0^2`). I solved it for `ic0 = 0.01` and again it was about `2/ic0^2`. The second point was originally `1/ic0^2`, which worked, but I realized that all the solutions I saw were about `2.7` or `2.8` times `1/ic0^2`. For the penatly `pen`, I picked a number that was bigger than that. The value returned will be negative when `p0` is too small and integration did not make it to `x2 == 1`; since `ic1 > 0`, the secant method will then increase `p0` on the next step.

Comment: How did you solved for `ic0=0.1` or `ic0=0.01` to confirm that `p0` goes like `1/ic0^2`? Why did you expect that in principle?

Comment: @resanrom For an initial value for `u'[-1]` in the IVP, pick successively things like `1`, `10`, `100`, etc. and examine the solution, what it looks like, and how close to the BC at `1` you get.  One could do that inside `Manipulate`, too and adjust the IC with a slider.  As for "in principle," I just guessed, from two data points, maybe more.  I forget.  I didn't have time to do the analysis; maybe someone else can. (Actually, all I could see from the calculations, is that it's close enough a guess for `FindRoot` to succeed, which I verified by moving the slider.)

Comment: I was trying to find details about `ExtrapolationHandler`, and I only found your answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63083/suppress-extrapolation-of-interpolating-function-in-a-contourplot/63153#63153). In particular, here, you write `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {p0 - pen &, "WarningMessage" -> False}` inside `ParametricNDSolveValue`. I didnt understand very well this line, why do I need to stablish a penalty? What does mean `"WarningMessage" -> False}`?

Comment: Also, `p0 - pen` in this `Extrapolationshandler` imposes some kind of contidion in the solution?

Comment: @resanrom I learned of `"ExtrapolationHandler"` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#comment88520_28341).  Extrapolation is what happens when the input to an interpolating function lies outside the domain. The handler is a function that is applied to such an input. Normally, a warning message is issued, but that can be turned off. A penalty is a common method to enforce a constraint when solving an equation. In this case, extrapolation happens when the integration did not reach the end at `x2 == 1`; the penalty indicates the

Comment: parameter caused the solution to evaluate to a value `<= p0`. If the integration completed (reached `x2 == 1`) the boundary value will be `>= p0`. The desired value of the parameter will be between those two values, unless in the first case, the solution improbably evaluates exactly to `p0`.

Comment: I saw it is an amazing tool. Let me try to define with you what  `ExtrapolationHandler` does in general. In general, then, `ExtrapolationHandler` is written as `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {extra &, "WarningMesage" -> False}`, where `extra` is the value of the interpolation function when we ask point outside the obtained domain, right?, and `"WarningMessage" ->False` that turns off the message that tells you are outside the domain, I got that.

Comment: When you ask for a value that it is outside the domain, you replace the `Interpolate` function with `extra`, right? As is said [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63083/suppress-extrapolation-of-interpolating-function-in-a-contourplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) with `extra` as `Indeterminate`.

Comment: When I played with the program, a simplified one, in which I suppress the `Dynamic` part. I separate a bit more `x20` and `x21`, then `pen=3/u0^2` leads to `p0=pen` as the solution. Does it mean that `extra` in `ExtrapolationHandler` must be zero?

Comment: Sorry if these lines of comments became too large, and if there is a rule here that tells you must delete large lines of comments, I will try to write a nice definition of `ExtrapolationHandler` below my question for future references.

Comment: @resanrom Your general idea about `ExtrapolationHandler` is right. The only rule I know is that comments are not for long discussions like this.

Comment: I agree. But I think this discussion is in some way useful for people looking for datails about `ExtrapolationHandler`. Moreover, since `ÈxtrapolationHandler` allow us to aplly the penaly method, is it possible to do it for a system of coupled PDEs? I mean, something like `"ExtrapolationHandler"->{{penalty1,penalty2,...}&, "WarningMessage"->False}`.